# Why does std::shared_ptr not have template argument for allocator and deleter?

Tags: c++, templates, memory

The `std::shared_ptr` of C++ comes with a constructor that takes a custom allocator and deleter for the `shared_ptr`:

```
template< class Y, class Deleter, class Alloc > 
shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d, Alloc alloc );
```

However the class itself doesn't know about template parameters for the same purpose. Most other template classes in the standard library have a template parameter for allocators. Why doesn't `shared_ptr` have the same?

Reason I am asking: I want to have a custom heap implementation to be used with all my standard library classes and the `shared_ptr` sticks out a bit due to it only taking the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` implements type-erased deleters. This adds some overhead (basically, a virtual function call) but makes the class template more flexible. Given that `std::shared_ptr` already has some overhead due to reference counting, type-erasure flexibility is acceptable for most users.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` has no paramter for allocator either, but it does have the `Deleter` as template parameter.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number -- `std::unique_ptr` doesn't allocate anything, so there is no reason for it to have an allocator.